# JavaScript window open 2 seperate windows. Communicate between them

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for a way to communicate between 2 popups with JavaScript.

All I have found so far has been questions about how to communinate between Main and Popup, but I want Popup 1 to update Popup 2. Update it's URL or other stuff.

Any idea?

Comment: i don't think it's possible, popup can talk to main only, so i don't think popup1 can directly talk to popup2. Maybe you should create a relationship of Popup1 <=> Main <=> popup2

Comment: Thanks Anthony C. That could be a reliable way and easy for other programmers to understand that relationship.

Answer (score 2):

While you can't have each popup directly communicate with each other, you can use the [`localStorage storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) event for each popup to set/get information from a single source:

Comment: Thanks. Though I haven't used localStorage yet, but that doesn't sound completely bad.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, assuming it is running on a server, would be to use [web sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).  With web sockets you could instantly communicate between all open processes to the server.  This avoids constantly polling your server for changes.  You can also use something like [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/) to get live updates.